# Background process no longer has access to .db file after I log out

Tags: server, ssh, java, process, sqlite

I have a java application which I start with...

```
nohup java -cp MyServer.jar > log.txt 2> errors.txt < /dev/null &
```

The application is just a web-service that provides a few methods to update a sqlite database.

When I start the application (with the above command), it works fine, and I can see in the log files that it is updating the database.

However, when I log out of my SSH session, the web-service fails when trying to access the database.

It returns...

```
java.sql.SQLException: path to 'dbrocket.db': '/home/rich/roketapp' does not exist
```

Obviously, that path does exist, as does the file.

If I reconnect to the Ubuntu server, it then starts working again (I'm not re-starting the application) so it's almost as if it loses some security rights when I log out.

The security on the file is

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 rich rich 3697664 Dec  5 09:27 dbroket.db
```

Maybe I need to change this, but I'd rather understand **why** this is happening.

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu/Java/Linux etc. so please bear with me if I'm missing something obvious.

Output from `df /home/rich/roketapp`

```
Filesystem          1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/home/rich/.Private 127147284 2561168 118084332   3% /home/rich
```

Comment: Is `/home/rich/rocketapp/` dynamically mounted when you log in and umounted when you log out? Maybe it is on a network share? When logged in, try `df /home/rich/rocketapp` and paste the output to your question.

Comment: @ridgy I've added the output of `df` to my question, it's not something **I'm** mounting and it's not on a network share. The path is where the Java app resides and it's still writing to the log file and error.txt file. So the path is still available.

Comment: You're using an encrypted home directory. You need to be logged in for it be accessible.

Comment: That sounds plausible, but how would the application continue running, and be able to write to the log.txt file and errors.txt if it no longer has access to that directory? Or is it because it obtained handles to these files at the point it was run?

Comment: @RichS yes, the OS keeps the file handle alive as long as the app doesn't close them